# Syntax for asp.net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How is the above syntax possible? i.e name : "Default" and why can't we use it for normal custom method calls

Answer (score 0):

Those are just the argument names. C# allows you to positionaly place arguments with specifying their names. This makes it readable.

For instance this is completely valid:

```
void Foo(string arg) { ... }

Foo(arg: "bar");
```